# Android: Fragments, SQLite and Loaders

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

So I've come to a point where I need to implement an SQLite database for my app.
Following "The Busy Coder's guide to Android Development" I have created a DatabaseHelper class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

One of my use cases is to run a query against the database and display the results on a `ListView` within a `Fragment` (I use fragments from the support library).

From what I understand, using `managedQuery()` is not really appropriate and even if it were it isn't recommended due to the fact that some of the logic encapsulated inside this method is actually executed on the main thread, specifically `reQuery()` which to my understanding is performed when the `Activity` is restarted.

So I've been trying to get acquainted with the `Loader` class for the first time, only to see this:

`"The only supplied concrete implementation of a Loader is CursorLoader, and that is only for use with a ContentProvider"`

My initial thought was to implement my own content provider and perhaps prevent other apps from getting access to it, then I read the following in the `ContentProvider` documentation via developer.android.com:

`"You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application."`

I've also been playing with this:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

Yet I am not familiar with this project, and not sure if it can be used on a production environment.

So, right now all I can think of is creating a bunch of `AsyncTask` instances within my `Fragment` and manage their lifecycle appropriately, make sure they're cancelled whenever needed and whatnot.

Are there any other options?

Comment: I would go with the SQLiteCursorLoader from CommonsWare, it seems to do exactly what you want. I don't see any issues using it a production application.

Comment: Do you need to just show the data from database or also you need to do manipulations on data?

Comment: @NickF in this context, all I want is to retrieve the data..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend Loader class in order to perform other Async work such as loading directly from your DB.

[Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-loader-to-load-data-directly-from-sqlite-database.html) is an example of that

---

**Edit:** added A better example of Loader usage.

Finally managed to find the tutorial that really helped me understand how things work.

By extending the loader class you can avoid messing with content observers and its quite easy to implement (at last)
the modifications that need to be taken in your code are

- Add implementation of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>`, where `D` is your data list (snippet 1)
- Create your loader class, copy snippet 2, and add the loading of your data from the DB
- Finally call the loaders 1 call for init and then for refreshing the restart call. (snippet 2 & 3)

***Snippet 1:*** How to "link" the loader with your fragment:

```
public static class AppListFragment extends ListFragment implements
      LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<SampleItem>> {

  public Loader<List<SampleItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) { 
     //...
     return new SampleLoader (getActivity());
  }

  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<SampleItem>> loader, List<SampleItem> data) {
    // ... 
     mAdapter.setData(data);

     if (isResumed()) {
       setListShown(true);
     } else {
       setListShownNoAnimation(true);
     }
    // ... 
 }

  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<SampleItem>> loader) { 
    // ... 
    mAdapter.setData(null);
    // ... 
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

***Snippet 2:*** Schema of your custom loader: (I have double commented the observer things as I believe that it is quite difficult to implement it from the beginning and you can simple recall the loader without messing with that automated refreshing)

```
public class SampleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<SampleItem>> {

  // We hold a reference to the Loader’s data here.
  private List<SampleItem> mData;

  public SampleLoader(Context ctx) {
    // Loaders may be used across multiple Activitys (assuming they aren't
    // bound to the LoaderManager), so NEVER hold a reference to the context
    // directly. Doing so will cause you to leak an entire Activity's context.
    // The superclass constructor will store a reference to the Application
    // Context instead, and can be retrieved with a call to getContext().
    super(ctx);
  }

  /****************************************************/
  /** (1) A task that performs the asynchronous load **/
  /****************************************************/

  @Override
  public List<SampleItem> loadInBackground() {
    // This method is called on a background thread and should generate a
    // new set of data to be delivered back to the client.
    List<SampleItem> data = new ArrayList<SampleItem>();

    // TODO: Perform the query here and add the results to 'data'.

    return data;
  }

  /********************************************************/
  /** (2) Deliver the results to the registered listener **/
  /********************************************************/

  @Override
  public void deliverResult(List<SampleItem> data) {
    if (isReset()) {
      // The Loader has been reset; ignore the result and invalidate the data.
      releaseResources(data);
      return;
    }

    // Hold a reference to the old data so it doesn't get garbage collected.
    // We must protect it until the new data has been delivered.
    List<SampleItem> oldData = mData;
    mData = data;

    if (isStarted()) {
      // If the Loader is in a started state, deliver the results to the
      // client. The superclass method does this for us.
      super.deliverResult(data);
    }

    // Invalidate the old data as we don't need it any more.
    if (oldData != null && oldData != data) {
      releaseResources(oldData);
    }
  }

  /*********************************************************/
  /** (3) Implement the Loader’s state-dependent behavior **/
  /*********************************************************/

  @Override
  protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mData != null) {
      // Deliver any previously loaded data immediately.
      deliverResult(mData);
    }

    // Begin monitoring the underlying data source.
    ////if (mObserver == null) {
      ////mObserver = new SampleObserver();
      // TODO: register the observer
    ////}

    //// takeContentChanged() can still be implemented if you want 
    ////     to mix your refreshing in that mechanism 
    if (takeContentChanged() || mData == null) {
      // When the observer detects a change, it should call onContentChanged()
      // on the Loader, which will cause the next call to takeContentChanged()
      // to return true. If this is ever the case (or if the current data is
      // null), we force a new load.
      forceLoad();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStopLoading() {
    // The Loader is in a stopped state, so we should attempt to cancel the 
    // current load (if there is one).
    cancelLoad();

    // Note that we leave the observer as is. Loaders in a stopped state
    // should still monitor the data source for changes so that the Loader
    // will know to force a new load if it is ever started again.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onReset() {
    // Ensure the loader has been stopped.
    onStopLoading();

    // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'mData'.
    if (mData != null) {
      releaseResources(mData);
      mData = null;
    }

    // The Loader is being reset, so we should stop monitoring for changes.
    ////if (mObserver != null) {
      // TODO: unregister the observer
     //// mObserver = null;
    ////}
  }

  @Override
  public void onCanceled(List<SampleItem> data) {
    // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
    super.onCanceled(data);

    // The load has been canceled, so we should release the resources
    // associated with 'data'.
    releaseResources(data);
  }

  private void releaseResources(List<SampleItem> data) {
    // For a simple List, there is nothing to do. For something like a Cursor, we 
    // would close it in this method. All resources associated with the Loader
    // should be released here.
  }

  /*********************************************************************/
  /** (4) Observer which receives notifications when the data changes **/
  /*********************************************************************/

  // NOTE: Implementing an observer is outside the scope of this post (this example
  // uses a made-up "SampleObserver" to illustrate when/where the observer should 
  // be initialized). 

  // The observer could be anything so long as it is able to detect content changes
  // and report them to the loader with a call to onContentChanged(). For example,
  // if you were writing a Loader which loads a list of all installed applications
  // on the device, the observer could be a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the
  // ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent, and calls onContentChanged() on the particular 
  // Loader whenever the receiver detects that a new application has been installed.
  // Please don’t hesitate to leave a comment if you still find this confusing! :)
  ////private SampleObserver mObserver;
}
```

***Snippet 3:*** How to call the loader for the first time (ONLY)

```
  // Initialize a Loader with an id. If the Loader with this id is not 
  // initialized before
  getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

***Snippet 4:*** For refreshing data (recalling the query)

```
 // Check if the loader exists and then restart it.
 if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) != null)
     getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

*Reference:*

- Snippet 1 : usage of loader extracted from [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html)
- Snippet 2 : [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html) for more info and logic read throughout the hole article
- Snippet 3 & 4: are just loader usage.

Full code of these is also uploaded by the creator on [github](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader)

Answer (score 8):

I think implementing content provider is a good idea, no matter that data will not be accessible outside of the application. It provides very modern interface and from my experience makes your application error prone to database locking issues and other db-specific problems.

I've implemented it in my latest project and I was very happy to use it.

Comment: Did you mean to say that implementing a content provider makes your application "immune" to locking issues rather than saying it makes your application "error prone" to locking issues?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) library, a lightweight Object Relational Mapping that can work for Android. This library will make your life easier . You don't need to create or update database by hand, you don't need to focus on managing database connection, all queries select, insert, update will be easier with a `DAO` approach (usually you don't need to write your own sql query) and a lot of features. They have [some examples](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_7.html#Android-Examples) that you can start with.

And if you want to use the `Loader`, there is a [ORMLite Extras](https://github.com/campnic/ormlite-android-extras) , additional functionality for ORMLite  available on `github` (You can use the support package which is compatible with support android library). Here is an example usage on my previous project:

```
public class EventsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
   private static final int LOADER_ID = EventsFragment.class.getName().hashCode();
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
   }

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layoutRoot = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_events, null);
    lvEvents = (ListView) layoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.lvEvents);   

    adapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity(), null, null);
    lvEvents.setAdapter(adapter);

    return layoutRoot;
}

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
       try {
           PreparedQuery<Event> query = getDatabaseHelper().getEventDao().getQuery();
           return getDatabaseHelper().getEventDao().getSQLCursorLoader(query );
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    try {
        adapter.setQuery(getDatabaseHelper().getEventDao().getQuery());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

    private OrmliteDatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper(){
         return ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getDatabaseHelper();
    }
 }
```

The adapter

```
 public class EventAdapter extends OrmliteCursorAdapter<Event>{

public EventAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, PreparedQuery<Event> query) {
    super(context, c, query);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View itemView, Context context, Event item) {
    TextView tvEventTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventTitle); 
    TextView tvEventStartDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventStartDate);

    tvEventTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    tvEventStartDate.setText(item.getFormatStartDate());
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_item_row, arg2, false);
    return retView;
}
 }
```

And a custom Dao which provides `PreparedQuery` for cursor adapter above:

```
public interface IEventDao extends Dao<Event, Integer>{
    PreparedQuery<Event> getQuery() throws SQLException;
    OrmliteCursorLoader<Event> getSQLCursorLoader(Context context, PreparedQuery<Event> query) throws SQLException;
}

public class EventDao extends AndroidBaseDaoImpl<Event, Integer> implements IEventDao{

public EventDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
    super(connectionSource, Event.class);
}

public EventDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource,
        DatabaseTableConfig<Event> tableConfig) throws SQLException {
    super(connectionSource, tableConfig);
}

@Override
public PreparedQuery<Event> getQuery() throws SQLException{
    return queryBuilder().prepare();
}
}
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 2):

If your database contains thousands of records consider madlymad's answer
If not keep it stupid and simple, use `SQLiteOpenHelper` and create a method that returns you your data as array of strings or define your one objects.
Also use custom/regular [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use the SQLiteOpenHelper to create my database. I have made Java classes for all the tables and when I get the data from my database I put it in an ArrayList. The ArrayList I then load into the adapter of the Listview.

Comment: As noted elsewhere this is probably good for smaller record sets and may have problems. Does it block the UI thread when running? If you have a strategy for using this in background threads could you update your answer to reflect that? I'd also be interested in seeing a good sample reference in the answer. - Thanks