# Loader for SQLite database, no ContentProvider

Tags: android, loader

Is not possible to use an interface LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks without use a ContentProvider? (in an easy way..)

Thank you

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/03/31/cwac-loaderex-failed-abstractions.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of well-received solutions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935904/android-fragments-sqlite-and-loaders) (you may want to review the answers and their references for ease of use). There is also an interesting article to walk you through an [approach that seems directly related to your request - **Android Custom Loader to Load Data Directly from SQLite Database**](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-loader-to-load-data-directly-from-sqlite-database.html). An interesting footnote found on [this sample](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html) indicates:

> 1 You don't need to worry about registering a listener for your Loader
>   unless you plan on using it without the LoaderManager. The
>   LoaderManager will act as this "listener" and will forward any results
>   that the Loader delivers to the LoaderCallbacks#onLoadFinished method.
>   ↩

However, I suggest you try merging the database calls found in the sample within an existing Master Detail Activity automatically created with Android Studio. The default DummyContent can be replaced with a custom class representing actual content in your database. At this point you would be using the proper activity and list fragment frameworks to manage the SQLite database calls.